# How do you start and stop the Spotlight server in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, spotlight, launchd, metadata

There are many forums answering this question for previous versions of MAC OSX, but 10.10 doesn't seem to have the service '`com.apple.metadata.mds.plist`' in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`. It has 3 others (`com.apple.metadata.mds.index.plist`, `com.apple.metadata.mds.scan.plist` and `com.apple.metadata.mds.spindump.plist`).

When I try any mdutil commands I get:

```
-07 08:55:25.673 mdutil[2360:239343] Metadata.framework [Error]: mdsCopyStorePaths failed: (268435459) (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Spotlight server is disabled.
```

Comment: According to the error message, Spotlight is disabled. How did you disable it? Undo that and I would assume `mdutil` would resume functioning.

Comment: It was disabled before upgrading to yosemite - the command to re-enable it must have changed

Answer (score 2):

I'm on 10.10, and I have this service.

```
$ ls -l /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1.6K Jul 30 01:33 com.apple.metadata.mds.index.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1.6K Jul 30 01:33 com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   922B Jul 30 01:33 com.apple.metadata.mds.scan.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   856B Jul 30 01:33 com.apple.metadata.mds.spindump.plist
```

The you can load/unload with this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Comment: Interesting - I don't have the com.apple.metadata.mds.plist there - hmm...

Comment: I recovered the file from a mac running 10.9 and it all works now - but I would be intrigued to see the contents of a 10.10 version. There isn't much in there...

Comment: Check out [here](http://pastebin.com/NaViMf4Y).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly I seemed to have lost the com.apple.metadata.mds.plist file from /System/Library/LaunchDaemons. I have replaced it with one from another machine and loaded it with `sudo launchctl load -w com.apple.metadata.mds.plist` and now everything to do with spotlight is working!